# Values in my array change despite being correct 3 lines earlier

Tags: python, arrays

I am making a code for a connect 4 game but you can twist a row after your go, I am very early in development and am trying to make the twist element of the game, however after I complete the twist function the values inside the array storing the game data just gives me zeros when I run the twist function the first time I print "GameArrays[y][Height - row]" it gives me the correct values however when I print it again it gives me the incorrect values. It is meant to produce the Y and Rs in the same array position but in the array indexed one more or less depending on the direction chosen

**Twist Function**

```
def twistRow(row, direction):
    rowArray = []
    for x in range(Width):
        rowArray.append(GameArrays[x][Height - row])
    twistArray = rowArray.copy()

    if direction == "L":
        firstItem = twistArray.pop(0)
        twistArray.append(firstItem)
    elif direction == "R":
        lastItem = twistArray.pop()
        twistArray.insert(0, lastItem)

    for y in range(Width):
        GameArrays[y][Height - row] = twistArray[y]
        print(GameArrays[y][Height - row])

    for z in range(Width):
        print(GameArrays[z][Height - row])
```

**Code that calls it**

```
check = 0
goTrack = 0
gameFinished = False
while check == 0:
    playsFirst = input("Who is going first? R- Red or Y- Yellow\n")
    if playsFirst == "R":
        print("Ok, Red goes first")
        check = 1
    elif playsFirst == "Y":
        print("Ok, Yellow goes first")
        check = 1
        goTrack = 1
    else:
        print("Invalid- Please Enter either R for Red or Y for Yellow")

while not gameFinished:
    if goTrack == 0:
        columnChosen = input("Red - Which column would you like to play in\n")
        playsCounter("R", int(columnChosen))
        goTrack += 1

    elif goTrack == 1:
        columnChosen = input("Yellow - Which column would you like to play in\n")
        playsCounter("Y", int(columnChosen))
        goTrack -= 1

    twistChoice = input("Which row would you like to twist? (Enter 0 for no twist)\n")
    if twistChoice == "0":
        print("Ok then")
    else:
        directionChoice = input("Which direction would you like to twist? (Enter L or R)\n")
        if directionChoice == "L":
            twistRow(int(twistChoice), directionChoice)
        elif directionChoice == "R":
            twistRow(int(twistChoice), directionChoice)
```

**Plays Counter Function**

```
def playsCounter(colour, column):
    counter = 0
    if 0 in GameArrays[column - 1]:
        playedIn = GameArrays[column - 1].copy()
        for x in playedIn:
            if x != 0:
                break
            else:
                counter += 1
                print(counter)
        playedIn[counter - 1] = colour
        GameArrays[column - 1] = playedIn
    else:
        print("Invalid- That Column is full")
        playAgain(colour)
```

Comment: Seems like a good case for https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ .

Comment: But litter your program with `print()` functions (hint: `print(f"{=some_var}")` will produce a nicely verbose output for `some_var`). Or step through it with a debugger.